# Binding is not working with dynamic data updates

Tags: wpf

I'm new in WPF and I have the following problem.

I have the following class with many properties , but here is only one property for example:

```
public class StatusData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string m_statusText = String.Empty;

    public StatusData()
    {
        m_statusText = "1234";
    }
    public string StatusText
    {
        get
        {
            return m_statusText;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_statusText != value)
            {
                m_statusText = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("StatusText");
            }
        }
    }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
   {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Another component of the project changes `StatusData` and calls `Update()` function in `MainWindow`.
So, `m_statusData` of this `MainWindow` has changed and I want update the `textbox` with `m_statusText` accordingly.

```
public class MainWindow
{
   private StatusData m_statusData = new StatusData();

    public MainWindow()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid1.DataContext = m_statusData ;         
    }

    public void Update(StatusData newStatusData)
    {
        m_statusData = newStatusData;            
    }    
}
```

Xaml code:

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplicationUpdateTextBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="myWin"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationUpdateTextBox"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded" >    

   <Grid Name="grid1">

      <TextBox  Text="{Binding  Path=StatusText}"  Name="textBox1"  />

   </Grid>
  </Window>
```

The question is : why the `textBox` is not updated with`newStatusData.StatusText`?

Comment: Does the Update method get called after the form is loaded?  Because you Update method will not update the DataContext.

Comment: Hi, @norlando, yes, the Update method called after the form is loaded. I can call grid1.DataContext = m_statusData in Update method, but according to design of project I need to call to Update every second approximately, so grid1.DataContext = m_statusData will be done every second. Could it be a performance issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you are assigning the grid's DataContext to m_statusData:

```
 grid1.DataContext = m_statusData ;
```

And here, you are reassigning m_statusData to something else:

```
   m_statusData = newStatusData;
```

The problem is that this has no effect on grid1.DataContext, which was set to the *previous* instance of m_statusData.

In this case, doing grid1.DataContext = newStatusData should solve your problem. However, a better solution would be to create a StatusData property which returns m_statusData. You can then do a RaisePropertyChanged() on it when m_statusData changes.

```
private void Update(StatusData newStatusData)
{
    StatusData = newStatusData;            
}

public StatusData StatusData
{
   get
   {
        return m_statusData;
   }
   set
   {
        m_statusData = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("StatusData");
   }
}
```

... and then in your XAML, bind your Grid's DataContext to the StatusData property

Edit:
To bind the grid's data context to the StatusData property, you can do this in your XAML:

```
<Grid Name="grid1" DataContext="{Binding StatusData}">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=StatusText}"  Name="textBox1"  />
</Grid>
```

You will also need to set the initial DataContext of your window, to make all of the other databindings work (this is a little strange and non-standard, but it will do the trick):

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: Hi Marty Dill. May I ask you 2 questions? Your first suggestion is works. Thanks. But if I need to call this Update method every 1 second (according to design of the project), then grid1.DataContext = m_statusData will be done every 1 second.  Could it be a performance issue? I like your second suggestion, but I didn't succeded to bind Grid's DataContext to the StatusData property
in xaml. Could you please suggest how I can do it? Thanks.

Comment: See my edit above for binding the grid's DataContext to the StatusData property in XAML. With regards to performance, calling Update every 1 second is highly unlikely to cause any issues, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `StatusData` has only 1 property: `StatusText`. If this property is the only thing you want to change with this code:

```
m_statusData = newStatusData;
```

You can change it to this:

```
m_statusData.StatusText = newStatusData.StatusText;
```

This code will fire the `PropertyChangedEvent` of `StatusData` class and that will change TextBox value.

Comment: Hi Maksim, actually I have about 20 such properties. So I try to find solution, which is not requiring assign for every property.Thanks.